# srp6 IntPtr to BigInteger

Tags: .net, openssl, biginteger, intptr

I have a server program which uses SRP6 for it's encryption. To accomplish this it makes use of the OpenSSL LIBEAY32.dll. It uses the BN functions and IntPtr, however I am completely mystified as to what is actually going on inside the DLL function. To make matters worse I'm not sure if there are some custom elements added to the encryption used.

To clear this up for me and so I can actually thoroughly understand the process I wanted to convert the code to make it use the BigInteger and perform the calculations outside of the DLL. But because my knowledge is severely lacking in this area, I was hoping to get a nudge in the right direction.

The following code calculates x. Now I have no idea why the byte array gets reversed. But I see this a lot in the code, the byte array gets reversed and then converted to a BN with the BN_bin2bn function. Is there a reason for this?

```
Public Sub CalculateX(ByVal I As Byte())
    'x = sha (s, I) , I = sha ( "username:password");'
    Dim buffer As Byte() = objSha1Managed.ComputeHash(salt.Concat(I).ToArray())

    Array.Reverse(buffer)
    _x = New BigInteger(buffer)
End Sub
```

Then we have the code to calculate v.

```
Private Sub CalculateV()
    'v = g^x % N'
    _BNv = BN_new("")
    Dim ptr1 As IntPtr = BN_CTX_new("")
    Dim x As IntPtr = BN_bin2bn(_x.ToByteArray(), _x.ToByteArray().Length, IntPtr.Zero, "")
    BN_mod_exp(_BNv, _BNg, x, _BNn, ptr1, "")

    Dim v() As Byte = New Byte(31) {}
    BN_bn2bin(_BNv, v, "")
End Sub
```

I tried to rewrite this code to the following. I already cleaned the code up a lot but you can still see I've tried all sorts of stuff: reversing byte array x again, adding 0 bytes for positive numbers. Where I am stuck is: I'm **assuming** that the byte array v() in the code above should have the same value as the byte array myV() in the code below. Yet I just can't get there. Is my assumption correct? If so, where would my mistake be? If not, how can I convert the entire project if I can't compare values?

```
Private Sub CalculateV()
    'v = g^x % N'
    'Dim BIGINTEGER_N As BigInteger = New BigInteger(N.Concat(New Byte() {0}).ToArray())'
    Dim BIGINTEGER_N As BigInteger = New BigInteger(N)
    Dim tempX As Byte() = _x.ToByteArray()
    Array.Reverse(tempX)
    Dim BIGINTEGER_X As BigInteger = New BigInteger(tempX.Concat(New Byte() {0}).ToArray())
    'Dim BIGINTEGER_X As BigInteger = New BigInteger(tempX)'
    Dim myV() As Byte = BigInteger.ModPow(New BigInteger(g), BIGINTEGER_X, BIGINTEGER_N).ToByteArray()
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have no idea why the byte array gets reversed. But I see this a lot in the code, the byte array gets reversed and then converted to a BN with the BN_bin2bn function. Is there a reason for this?

Microsoft APIs are usually little-endian, while crypto code often works with a "natural" byte ordering, which is big-endian. Additionally, some CPUs, like Intel based IA-32, are little-endian. At minimum, its sometimes easier just do do what the processor does. Since Microsoft mostly runs on Intel processors, it uses little-endian since its natural for the processor.

Regarding *"crypto code often works with a "natural" byte ordering ..."*, libraries like Botan, Crypto++ and OpenSSL run on a number of platforms so they use a natural representation. They also often provide specialized implementations for ARM, IA-32, PPC, SPARC, but its an internal detail usually hidden from API users. A counter example of hiding is from OpenSSL and [configuring with `enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128`](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options):

> Use on little endian platforms when GCC supports `__uint128_t`. ECDH is
>   about 2 to 4 times faster. Not enabled by default because Configure
>   can't determine it. Enable it if your compiler defines
>   `__SIZEOF_INT128__`, the CPU is little endian and it tolerates unaligned data access.

---

I don't use .Net and interop too often (its been years since the last time), so I'm going to leave the .Net question to the .Net experts.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought it might be endian related. So if I get this correct, endian is basically. You have a number 10 on two computers. On big-endian it's noted as 1010. On little-endian it's noted as 0101? Is this assumption correct?